# How can i run particular url (not home page) without hash using angular on node server?

Tags: angular

I am facing an issue related to angular routing on server. I use URL without having hash(#) symbol in it.
Withhash:
https://localhost:4200/#/activity-details/818659/false
Withouthash:
https://localhost:4200/activity-details/818659/false

Its works locally fine, but after deployment on node server it show me error 'Cannot GET /activity-details/818659/false'

with hash it work fine but i want to do this without hash in url.

without hash i am using: 
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]

with hash i was using
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes),{usehash: true}],

Is it handle on server side? how?
Is it handle in routing? how?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment):

> **Routed apps must fallback to index.html** 
> If the app uses the Angular router, you must configure the server to return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file that it does not have. 
>  A static server routinely returns index.html when it receives a request for http://www.example.com/. But it rejects http://www.example.com/heroes/42 and returns a 404 - Not Found error unless it is configured to return index.html instead.

If you run a fully static server, this generates an error, as the search page does not exist on the server. Using **Express.js**, for example, you can catch these requests and returns the index.html file.

```js
app.post(...)
app.get(...)
app.use((req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/index.html")))
```

**Static servers cofigurations:**

Nginx:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

Firebase Hosting:

```
"rewrites": [ {
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
} ]
```

Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: Was this helpful? let me know if you still have a problem, if it solved your problem please consider accepting the answer.